# How is a good packaging strategy in Android

Tags: android, project, structure, package, code-organization

I have developed several Android apps, and I am still not sure about how to structure the classes into different packages.

For example, imagine that we are building a book store app which consists in the 
BookListActivity and BookDownloadActivity.

The BookListActivity uses a ListView, and it needs a list adapter. The BookDownloadActivity needs the BookDownloadAsyncTask.

I've seen people structuring the code like this:

```
src/com/company/bookapp\
                  + activity\
                  |   +-BookListActivity.java
                  |   +-BookDownloadActivity.java  
                  |  
                  + adapter\
                  |    +-BookListAdapter.java
                  |
                  + asynctask\
                       +-BookDownloadAsyncTask.java
```

This structure makes sense in the way that we have a package for all the Activities. However, I think this sees java packages just like folders, drawers into where put stuff. 
If we do this the BookListAdapter class and some of its methods need to be public. I'd like to use java packages not like a filesystem in where you organize files in different folders, but like some kind of "namespaces", taking the full benefits from the java visibility modifier, including the package visibility.

So, as BookListAdaper is only used in the BookListActivity, I would like it to have package access level. The same goes for the BookDownloadAsyncTask, which is only used in the BookDownloadActivity.

Of course in this example the Adapter and the AsyncTask are trivial and small, so we could write them in their respective activities as nested classes. But imagine that the classes the Activities use are bigger or more than one, and again, are specific to that Activity

From this perspective I'm tempted to do:

```
src/com/company/bookapp\
                  + list\
                  |   +-BookListActivity.java
                  |   +-BookListAdapter.java  
                  |  
                  + download\
                       +-BookDownloadActivity.java
                       +-BookDownloadAsyncTask.java
```

With this approach only the Activites would be visible to the rest of the app, and the classes they use have package visibility and the rest of the app does not know about them, which I think it is more encapsulated and better.

However, do this mean that we should have a different package for each Activity?  What if two Activities use the same Adapter?

I'm interested in knowing what you guys are doing in this regard, as well as other related questions, as where to place the extended views, for example.

Comment: Voting to close, sorry, since I believe this is mainly opinion based and likely to start a comment storm.  Personally, the only criteria I use is visibility and hence encapsulation.  I see all other criteria as personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Classes from other packages, so you can split it up however you like. 
I always keep mine in MVC packages.

But if you create a protectet Class or method it can only be used in the same packages.

Comment: (Model, View, Control)